# MongoDB data grouping with aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

I have data collection like this:

```
> db.LogBuff.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("578899d5d2b76f77d083f16c"), "SUBJECT" : "DD", "SYS" : "A" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("578899d5d2b76f77d083f16d"), "SUBJECT" : "AA", "SYS" : "B" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("578899d5d2b76f77d083f16e"), "SUBJECT" : "BB", "SYS" : "A" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("578899d5d2b76f77d083f16f"), "SUBJECT" : "AA", "SYS" : "C" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("578899d5d2b76f77d083f170"), "SUBJECT" : "BB", "SYS" : "A" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("578899d5d2b76f77d083f171"), "SUBJECT" : "BB", "SYS" : "A" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("578899d5d2b76f77d083f172"), "SUBJECT" : "CC", "SYS" : "B" }
```

And I want to extract output as below (with distinct "SYS" values)

```
{"SUBJECT" : "AA", "SYS" : ["A","B","C","D"]}
{"SUBJECT" : "BB", "SYS" : ["A","B","C","D"]}
{"SUBJECT" : "CC", "SYS" : ["A","B","C"]}
```

Here is my code and I am stuck in the middle, please help me to sort this

```
db.LogBuff.aggregate([{
     "$unwind": "$SYS"
}, {
     "$group": {
             _id: {
                     "_id": "$SUBJECT"
             },
             SYST: {
                     $addToSet: "$SYS"
             }
     }
}, {
     "$unwind": "$SYST"
}, {
     "$group": {
             _id: {
             "SUBJECT": "$_id",
                     "SYST":"$SYST"
             }
     }
}])
```

Comment: What's the use of the `$unwind` operator in the first pipeline when the `SYS` field is not an array? Why don't you just run `db.LogBuff.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$SUBJECT",
            "sys": { "$addToSet": "$SYS" }
        }
    }
])`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just group by the `_id`, and `addToSet` the SYS values:

```
db.LogBuff.aggregate([
    {
     "$group": {
             _id: {
                     "_id": "$SUBJECT"
             },
             SYST: {
                     $addToSet: "$SYS"
             }
        }
    }
])
```

No need for unwind, one `group` should get you the desired result.

Result of group aggregation on your example data:

```
{ "_id" : { "_id" : "CC" }, "SYST" : [ "B" ] }
{ "_id" : { "_id" : "BB" }, "SYST" : [ "A" ] }
{ "_id" : { "_id" : "AA" }, "SYST" : [ "C", "B" ] }
{ "_id" : { "_id" : "DD" }, "SYST" : [ "A" ] }
```

Comment: Thank you very much